# Mysql2::Client で複数のSQL文を実行したい

Tags: ruby, mysql

`ruby`で`sql`文を書いたテキストファイル`sql.txt`を読み込み、`mysql2`で実行したいのですが、うまく行きません。

```
# DB設定
db = Mysql2::Client.new(...)


# sql文の読み込み
sql = ''
File.open("./sql.txt","r") do |f|
    sql = f.read
end

# 実行
db.query(sql)
```

`sql.txt`の中に1つの`sql`を書いた場合はうまくいくのですが、複数かくとエラーがでます。
なにかよい方法はないでしょうか。

成功する`sql.txt`

```
SELECT *
FROM `test`;
```

失敗する`sql.txt`

```
SELECT *
FROM `test`;
SELECT *
FROM `test`;
```

Answer (score 4):

Mysql2::Client.new に `:flags => Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS` を与えると複数のSQL文を実行できます。結果を取り出したい場合には、次のようにします。

```
result = db.query(sql)
pp result.first
while db.next_result
  result = db.store_result
  pp result.first
end
```

参考: [brianmario/mysql2: Multiple result sets](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#multiple-result-sets%20Multiple%20result%20sets)

Answer (score 1):

どうしてもプログラム中で複文を実行しなければならない場合であれば[yasuさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/7052/5793)の通りです。

ファイルに保存されたSQLを実行したいだけであれば、

```
$ mysql dbname < sql.txt
```

でもできます。

[yasuさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/7052/5793)の通り、複文を扱う場合結果の取得が面倒になるので、ファイルから読み込みつつ1つのSQL単位で実行するという手もあります。

```
sql = ''
IO.foreach("./sql.txt") do |line|
  sql += line
  if sql =~ /;\s*\z/ #セミコロンで終わっている行が現れたらSQLの区切りと見なす
    db.query(sql)
    sql = ''
  end
end
```